# How to fix chrome/explorer crash when launching a For-loop?

Tags: google-chrome, for-loop, dreamweaver

Trying to make a loop that shows all the numbers in 3 times multiplication table, from 0 to 999. Every time I "launch" the .html with the script everything crashes.

```
<script>
for (var i = 0; i <=999; i+3 ) {
    console.log(i);
}
</script>
```

Chrome freezes, and after a few seconds, it says that the tab isn't responding and it just dies.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Found out about it. Missed a "=" between i+ and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
for (var i = 0; i <=999; i=i+3 ) {
    console.log(i);
}
</script>
```